# What class should i use to swipe between views?

Tags: ios, objective-c

in my app when user click to "Photos" button, i want to load set of 4 views. In every view there is should be image that cover whole view, just photo of something, that downloaded through link saved to NSString.

What class should i use to swipe between views? What i want is similar to default Photos app. When user click on photo he can swipe left-right to see previous or next view with image.

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?  There are a few different ways to accomplish this... but have you even tried anything yet?  StackOverflow is a "I tried this but couldn't get it to work--how do I accomplish this?" sort of a site.  If you're looking to have someone write code for you, you're looking for Careers2.0

Comment: Why you so offensive? When i check developer site, there is said: "UIPageView controller is for animated books with curl animation", and "ScrollView" only contain two view. I do not need any code, i just want to know class that can manage such things.

Comment: You didn't even include THAT information in the question.  I asked you about what you tried.  If you read the docs on Page View and Scroll View and those weren't going to work, that information should be included in the question.  Programming very much so is the scientific method of trial and errors.  You're wasting people's time by not including your errors and explaining why these options don't work for you.

Comment: I wouldn't give up too quickly on `UIPageViewController`. It is very well suited to this problem. And effective iOS 6, it has a `transitionStyle` of `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` (a non-page-curl effect).

Comment: Thank you guys, that will do. And sorry about not-constructive topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIScrollView class to create photos viewer view.
Check out [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content)

Answer (score 1):

Use `UICollectionView` . This is easier if you are supporting iOS 6 and later.

You can use one section and 4 items for your views.

Comment: Thank you sleepwalkerfx.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/
a good tutorial. Return 1 section and 4 views to datasource delegate for your case.

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionView` class Apple introduced in `iOS 6`. It's used to display a grid of cells, and what better to display in those cells than some beautiful photos from 500px.[**Tutorial Here**](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/uicollectionview-example)